# How to keep return code and log of sub function in bash

Tags: bash

I want to run a sub function(with some interactive operation like **read**) and keep it's log.

Original

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo "Error"
  return 1
}
bar() {
  local data
  read -p "data=" data
  echo "OK: $data"
  return 0
}
foo 
echo "Return code=$?"
bar
echo "Return code=$?"
```

After keep the log

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo "Error"
  return 1
}
bar() {
  local data
  read -p "data=" data
  echo "OK: $data"
  return 0
}
LOG=my.log
foo | tee -a $LOG
echo "Return code=$?"
bar | tee -a $LOG
echo "Return code=$?"
```

Comment: By default, the exit status of a pipe is the exit status of the last command in it. You can try setting the **pipefail** option (`set -o pipefail`) but you may still get a wrong exit code if the `tee` command in your pipe fails for some reason (e.g. has problems writing data to the log file).

Answer (score 0):

Use a named pipe to send the return value:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo "Error"
  return 1
}
bar() {
  echo "OK"
  return 0
}

rm -f retcode
trap 'rm -f retcode' EXIT
mkfifo retcode

LOG=my.log
{
     foo
     echo $? > retcode
} | tee -a $LOG &
read rc < retcode
echo "Return code=$rc"
{
    bar
    echo $? > retcode
} | tee -a $LOG &
read rc < retcode
echo "Return code=$rc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use process substitution to run `tee`. This takes advantage of the fact that the return code of the process inside `>(...)` is lost.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo "Error"
  return 1
}
bar() {
  echo "OK"
  return 0
}
LOG=my.log
foo > >(tee -a $LOG )
echo "Return code=$?"
bar > >( tee -a $LOG )
echo "Return code=$?"
```

Comment: is it possible to redirect stderr & stdout?

Comment: I've test this, but my bar function require interactive operation. could I still keep log?